# How to construct this in regular expression

Tags: regex

I have file names that end in yyyymmdd, eg: myFile.20090601, myFile20090708 , etc

I want to grep for a pattern in all files from June 08 to July 07 of 2009, ie: 20090609 to 20090707

How can I do a regex in one go?

I tried:

```
grep 'myPattern' *20090(6(09|[1-3][0-9])|70[1-7])
```

Comment: Why would you want to use a regular expression for this?

Comment: I want to grep for a pattern in those files.

Comment: +1 - not sure why this was downvoted - i wish people would leave comments when they downvote so we can use them to appreciate where they are coming from

Comment: http://nregex.com/nregex/default.aspx is a great site to try out regex's

Comment: I can understand downvoting, because he is NOT talking about regular expressions, but, rather, regular Unix pattern matching, which is not regex.

The question should be rather "how do I list files according to a regular expression" or "how do I list these files with unix pattern matching".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
20090(6(09|[1-3][0-9])|70[1-7])$
```

or

```
20090(6(0[89]|[1-3][0-9])|70[1-7])$
```

depending on whether you meant 8th or 9th of July (your question seems contradictory there).

Comment: Actually, I meant how to I construct it so I can use it to grep for a a pattern in those files. As in I should be able to do:

grep 'myPattern' *20090(6(09|[1-3][0-9])|70[1-7])$ 

But it returns an error when I do this.

Comment: ls -1 myFile.* | grep '20090(6(0[89]|[1-3][0-9])|70[1-7])$' | xargs grep <pattern>

Comment: *20090(6(09|[1-3][0-9])|70[1-7])$  is not a regex, and it won't match what youe want. Also, the shell doesn't expand regexes... and a regex won't match a date range...

Comment: @Saobi: Try adding the -E option to the first grep.

Comment: Lars suggestion works, but he missed -E to the grep. If it still doesn't work, there's something you are not telling us that is relevant. Lars, you ought to post an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep 'myPattern' `ls | grep -E "20090(6(09|[1-3][0-9])|70[1-7])"`
```

This works roughly as follows. Take a list of files in the current directory (`ls`), filter that using the date regex (`ls | grep ...`), then perform a grep search using your pattern, on the list of files that is produced (`grep 'myPattern' ...`). The back-ticks surrounding the `ls | grep ...` executes that part of the command and substitutes in the output of that command into the surrounding command. So if it produced output like "`file1 file2 file3`", then it would result in a command like `grep 'myPattern' file1 file2 file3`.

Comment: You should change " into ', otherwise, depending on the shell, the wildcard might get expanded.

Comment: I think that there should be no asterisk at the beginning of the grep -E parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a perl/python script (or any other scripting language) that takes 3 parameters:

1. The pattern
2. Start date as yyyymmdd
3. End date as yyyymmdd

It would :

1. decode start and end date.
2. loop through the files in a folder
3. decode any dates in the filename
4. check if it's between the dates, and grep the pattern

Answer (score 0):

The range of valid dates is 06–30 for June and 01—07 for July. Because the ranges of days are dissimilar, we should use separate regexes for each month.  These are

```
/2009 06 (09 | [12][0-9] | 30)/x
```

(Notice how the day ranges are divided into cases depending on the tens place, because there are different conditions on what is valid for the units place depending.)

And

```
/2009 07 0[1-7]/x
```

and then we can join them into

```
/(2009 06 (09 | [12][0-9] | 30)) | (2009 07 0[1-7])/x
```

and then factor out the common points (may not be the best for readabilty) and add the end-of-line assertion:

```
/2009 0 (6 (09 | [12][0-9] | 30)) | (7 0[1-7]) $/x
```